# Why is .or_else() formulated to be called twice?

Tags: error-handling, rust

The [`Result` docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else) give the following explanation for the `.or_else()` method:

> `fn or_else<F, O: FnOnce(E) -> Result<T, F>>(self, op: O) -> Result<T, F>`
>
> Calls op if the result is Err, otherwise returns the Ok value of self.
>
> This function can be used for control flow based on result values.
>
> Examples
>
> `fn sq(x: u32) -> Result<u32, u32> { Ok(x * x) }`
>
> `fn err(x: u32) -> Result<u32, u32> { Err(x) }`
>
> `assert_eq!(Ok(2).or_else(sq).or_else(sq), Ok(2));`
>
> `assert_eq!(Ok(2).or_else(err).or_else(sq), Ok(2));`
>
> `assert_eq!(Err(3).or_else(sq).or_else(err), Ok(9));`
>
> `assert_eq!(Err(3).or_else(err).or_else(err), Err(3));`

I *think* can parse the `or_else` type annotation with more whitespace:

```
fn or_else<F,                           // F being the return type of the Result?
           O: FnOnce(E) -> Result<T, F> // the function to run instead if error
          > 
           (self, op: O)                // arguments to the `.or_else()` method
-> Result<T, F>                         // return type is again Result
```

Assuming I've got that right, does that mean `.or_else()` simply gives you a `Result` with the `Error` replaced with the return value of the `op` function?

I can understand returning a `Result` yet again, since all code downstream of possibly error-throwing code is "stained" with the possibility of further errors (and it's up to the caller to handle that). But why the doubled calls in the examples? There are a couple different permutations, but I'm not sure what they're trying to show (or if that doubled `or_else()` pattern is idiomatic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example may be a bit unfortunate, because it tries to show at the same time how does `or_else` work, and why would you use it.

To split it into two parts. First what does `or_else` actually do. If you get call it on `Ok` value, it passes the `Ok` value. If you call it on `Err` value, it executes the function. This example should be enough:

```
Ok(2).or_else(sq), Ok(2) // not called
Ok(2).or_else(err), Ok(2) // not called
Err(2).or_else(sq), Ok(4) // called, succeeds
Err(2).or_else(err), Err(3) // called, fails
```

Now, the why would you use it part. Imagine you're doing some operation which has many alternative approaches. For example you're trying to install some package on linux, but don't care which package manager is available - you're just going to brute-force it. With all the functions returning `Result<...>` you could do this:

```
install_with_apt().
    or_else(install_with_yum).
    or_else(install_with_pacman).
    or_else(install_with_dnf).
    or_else...
```

You'll know that if you got back `Ok`, at least one of those succeeded and if you get back `Err` all of them failed. The doubled `.or_else()` usage in the example if likely just trying to show you can easily chain this call.

Comment: So, just to be clear, `.or_else()` is no substitute for `try!()`?